# Format date produced by variable in SilverStripe function

Tags: php, date, silverstripe

I have a function that is meant to get some events data from the SilverStripe admin, and one of the variables is meant to hold a date. I want to format the date but how I have things set up at the moment, I am seeing the date output twice in a row for each event:

```
public function getCalendarEvents(){
    if(Director::is_ajax()){
        $allEvents = array();

        foreach(CalendarEvents::get() as $Event){
            $date = $Event->EventDate.date('m-d-Y');//this is the variable I want to format
            $title = $Event->EventTitle;
            $link = $Event->EventLink;
            $time = $Event->EventTime;

            if(!array_key_exists($date, $allEvents)){
            $allEvents[$date] = array(
                array($time, $title)
              );
            }
            else{
                $existingEvents = $allEvents[$date];
                array_push($existingEvents, array(
                    array($time, $title)
                ));
                $allEvents[$date] = $existingEvents;
            }
        }
        return json_encode($allEvents);
    }
    else{
      return CalendarEvents::get();
    }
}
```

And example of what this function produces is:

> {"2015-07-0207-15-2015":[["18:00:00","Knowledge is Power"]],

How can I edit my code to prevent the date from being displayed twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Event->EventDate.date('m-d-Y')
```

is a concatenation of two strings isn't it?

$Event->EventDate (the SS date) concatenated with date('m-d-Y') (this php date)

maybe you should do...

```
$date = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($Event->EventDate))
```